# Refresh shipping rates on city select field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to update/refresh the shipping rates on city change, so far I have managed to do so only by refreshing the page manually.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'check_minimum_and_city', 10, 2 );
function check_minimum_and_city($rates, $package){
    $selected_city = WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_city');
    $price_thirty = array('bat-yam','hulon','azur','tel-aviv-yafo','givatayim','ramat-gan','bnei-brak','rishon-letzion','netaim','yavne','kfar-nagid','galiya','ben-zakai','beit-gamliel');
    $price_fifty = array('einot','gan-shlomo','beit-oved','aseret','givat-brener','irus','misgav-dov','givton','kerem-yavne','beit-raban','rehovot','beit-elezri','beit-hanan','kvuzat-yavne','kfar-bilu','bnei-darom','nir-galim','kiryat-ekron','gedera','nes-tziona','kanot','gan-darom','netayim','mishmar-hashiva','gan-sorek','beit-dagan','ganot','beit-hanan-irus','hemed');
    $price_sixty = array('savion','ganei-tikva','or-yehuda','kiryat-ono','yehud','petah-tikva','ramat-hasharon','herzliya','kfar-shmariyahu','rishpon','raanana','kfar-saba','tsafria','beer-yaakov','netser-sireni','nir-tzvi','ramla','matsliax','bnaya','kfar-aviv');
    if(WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0] == 'local_pickup:13'){            
        $minimum = 0;       
    }else{      
        $minimum_thirty = 100;
        $minimum_fifty = 150;
        $minimum_sixty = 200;
        if(in_array($selected_city, $price_thirty)){
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:18']);
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:19']);
            if(WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum_thirty){
                throw new Exception( 
                    sprintf( 'סכום ההזמנה הנוכחית שלך עומד על %s, מינימום הזמנה לפני משלוח הינו %s.' , 
                        wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal ),
                        wc_price( $minimum_thirty )
                    )
                );  
            }           
        }elseif(in_array($selected_city, $price_fifty)){
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:9']);
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:19']);
            if(WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum_fifty){
                throw new Exception( 
                    sprintf( 'סכום ההזמנה הנוכחית שלך עומד על %s, מינימום הזמנה לפני משלוח הינו %s.' , 
                        wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal ),
                        wc_price( $minimum_fifty )
                    )
                );
            }
        }elseif(in_array($selected_city, $price_sixty)){
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:9']);
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:18']);
            if(WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum_sixty){
                throw new Exception( 
                    sprintf( 'סכום ההזמנה הנוכחית שלך עומד על %s, מינימום הזמנה לפני משלוח הינו %s.' , 
                        wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal ),
                        wc_price( $minimum_sixty )
                    )
                );
            }
        }       
        return $rates;
    }   
}
```

When I select a city field (dropdown custom list) I get the shipping cost I have made through the woocommerce settings but when I change it it does not update the rates.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'city_dropdown_field' );
function city_dropdown_field( $fields ) {

    $city_args = wp_parse_args( array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            ''                  => '',
            'yavne'             => 'יבנה',
            'kfar-nagid'        => 'כפר הנגיד',
            'galiya'            => 'גאליה',
            'ben-zakai'         => 'בן זכאי',
            'beit-gamliel'      => 'בית גמליאל',
            'bnaya'             => 'בניה',
            'einot'             => 'עינות',
            'kfar-aviv'         => 'כפר אביב',
            'gan-shlomo'        => 'גן שלמה',
            'beit-oved'         => 'בית עובד',
            'aseret'            => 'עשרת',
            'givat-brener'      => 'גבעת ברנר',
            'irus'              => 'אירוס',
            'misgav-dov'        => 'משגב דב',
            'givton'            => 'גיבתון',
            'kerem-yavne'       => 'כרם יבנה',
            'beit-raban'        => 'בית רבן',
            'rehovot'           => 'רחובות',
            'beit-elezri'       => 'בית אלעזרי',
            'beit-hanan'        => 'בית חנן',
            'kvuzat-yavne'      => 'קבוצת יבנה',
            'kfar-bilu'         => 'כפר בילו',
            'bnei-darom'        => 'בני דרום',
            'nir-galim'         => 'ניר גלים',
            'kiryat-ekron'      => 'קרית עקרון',
            'gedera'            => 'גדרה',
            'nes-tziona'        => 'נס ציונה',
            'kanot'             => 'כנות',
            'netayim'           => 'נטעים',
            'gan-darom'         => 'גן דרום',
            'givatayim'         => 'גבעתיים',
            'ramat-gan'         => 'רמת גן',
            'tel-aviv-yafo'     => 'תל אביב - יפו',
            'bnei-brak'         => 'בני ברק',
            'ramat-hasharon'    => 'רמת השרון',
            'herzliya'          => 'הרצליה',
            'kfar-shmariyahu'   => 'כפר שמריהו',
            'rishpon'           => 'רישפון',
            'raanana'           => 'רעננה',
            'kfar-saba'         => 'כפר סבא',
            'bat-yam'           => 'בת ים',
            'hulon'             => 'חולון',
            'azur'              => 'אזור',
            'savion'            => 'סביון',
            'ganei-tikva'       => 'גני תקווה',
            'or-yehuda'         => 'אור יהודה',
            'kiryat-ono'        => 'קרית אונו',
            'yehud'             => 'יהוד',
            'petah-tikva'       => 'פתח תקווה',
            'rishon-letzion'    => 'ראשון לציון',
            'mishmar-hashiva'   => 'משמר השבעה',
            'gan-sorek'         => 'גן שורק',
            'beit-dagan'        => 'בית דגן',
            'ganot'             => 'גנות',
            'beit-hanan-irus'   => 'בית חנן אירוס',
            'hemed'             => 'חמד',
            'tsafria'           => 'צפריה',
            'beer-yaakov'       => 'באר יעקב',
            'netser-sireni'     => 'נצר סירני',
            'nir-tzvi'          => 'ניר צבי',
            'ramla'             => 'רמלה',
            'matsliax'          => 'מצליח',
            'clear'             => true 
        ),
    ), $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $city_args;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = $city_args;

    return $fields;

}
```

Tried using this jQuery but nothing does the work

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_shipping_city_refresh_display' );
function checkout_shipping_city_refresh_display() {
    // On checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?><script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // Shipping fias code change & input events
        $(document.body).on( 'change', 'select[name=billing_city]', function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Help is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have Managed to resolve the issue and here is my solution, the answer was in corrected AJAX call and changing from multiple shipping rates to one and changing the rate by code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){    
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_shipping_city_refresh_display' );
function checkout_shipping_city_refresh_display() {
    // On checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?><script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).on('change', 'select[name=billing_city]', function(){
         var requested_city = jQuery(this).val();
         ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>'; // get ajaxurl

            var data = {
                    'action': 'get_and_set_shipping_rate',
                    'city': requested_city
                };
    
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajaxurl, // this will point to admin-ajax.php
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            jQuery('.shipping_method:checked').trigger('change');
                        });
                    }
                });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
function get_and_set_shipping_rate(){
    $shipping_city = $_POST['city'];
    $shipping_cost = get_shipping_cost_by_city($shipping_city);
    setcookie('shipping_city_cost', $shipping_cost, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); 
    $_COOKIE['shipping_city_cost'] = $shipping_cost;
    echo $shipping_cost;
    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_and_set_shipping_rate', 'get_and_set_shipping_rate' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_and_set_shipping_rate', 'get_and_set_shipping_rate' );

function get_shipping_cost_by_city( $city ) {
    $cost = 30;
        $price_thirty = array('bat-yam','hulon','azur','tel-aviv-yafo','givatayim','ramat-gan','bnei-brak','rishon-letzion','netaim','yavne','kfar-nagid','galiya','ben-zakai','beit-gamliel');
        $price_fifty = array('einot','gan-shlomo','beit-oved','aseret','givat-brener','irus','misgav-dov','givton','kerem-yavne','beit-raban','rehovot','beit-elezri','beit-hanan','kvuzat-yavne','kfar-bilu','bnei-darom','nir-galim','kiryat-ekron','gedera','nes-tziona','kanot','gan-darom','netayim','mishmar-hashiva','gan-sorek','beit-dagan','ganot','beit-hanan-irus','hemed');
        $price_sixty = array('savion','ganei-tikva','or-yehuda','kiryat-ono','yehud','petah-tikva','ramat-hasharon','herzliya','kfar-shmariyahu','rishpon','raanana','kfar-saba','tsafria','beer-yaakov','netser-sireni','nir-tzvi','ramla','matsliax','bnaya','kfar-aviv');
    
        // SET HERE the default cost (when "calculated cost" is not yet defined)
        if(in_array($city, $price_thirty)){
            $cost = 30;
        }elseif(in_array($city, $price_fifty)){
            $cost = 50;
        }elseif(in_array($city, $price_sixty)){
            $cost = 60;
        }
    return $cost;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'update_shipping_costs_based_on_cart_session_custom_data', 10, 2);
function update_shipping_costs_based_on_cart_session_custom_data( $rates, $package ){
    $selected_city = WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_city');
    $calculated_cost = get_shipping_cost_by_city($selected_city);

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // SET HERE the default cost (when "calculated cost" is not yet defined)
    $cost = '30';

    // Iterating though Shipping Methods
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate_values ) {
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;

        // For "Flat rate" Shipping" Method only
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $method_id ) {
            if( ! empty( $calculated_cost ) ) {
                $cost = $calculated_cost;
            }
            // Set the rate cost
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cost, 2);
            
            WC()->session->set( 'shipping_calculated_cost', $rates[$rate_id]->cost );
            
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                    $taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cost, 2 );
                    $has_taxes = true;
                } else {
                    $has_taxes = false;
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_id]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```